# Unable to increase file descriptors for rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to increase file descriptors for Rabbitmq server.

Machine details:

```
root@rabbitmq-stats-node:/home/# uname -a
Linux rabbitmq-stats-node 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u1 (2017-02-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here are the details of configuration parameters changed:

```
root@rabbitmq-stats-node:/home/# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
500000

root@rabbitmq-stats-node:/home/# tail -n1 /etc/pam.d/common-session
session required pam_limits.so

root@rabbitmq-stats-node:/home/# tail -n1 /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive
session    required   pam_limits.so

root@rabbitmq-stats-node:/home/# tail -n4 /etc/security/limits.conf 
*           soft    nofile          65536
*           hard    nofile          500000
root           soft    nofile          65536
root           hard    nofile          500000

root@rabbitmq-stats-node:/home/# sysctl -p 
fs.file-max = 500000

root@rabbitmq-stats-node:/home/# sudo service rabbitmq-server restart

root@rabbitmq-stats-node:/home/# sudo reboot
```

After all configuration changes, I am unable to change file desciptors limit.

```
root@rabbitmq-stats-node:/home/# rabbitmqctl status | grep -A1 descriptors
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,924},{total_used,13},{sockets_limit,829},{sockets_used,3}]},
```

I can see changed limit when I enter,

```
root@rabbitmq-stats-node:/home/# ulimit -n
65536
```

Though the changes are not reflected in rabbitmq installation.

I also tried adding ulimit line to `/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-env` file. Though rabbitmq server doesnot start after adding this change. Error thrown:

```
ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file /etc/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service.d/limits.conf adding this solves the problem,

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=300000
```

Further info available here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html
[Controlling System Limits on Linux]

Answer (score 0):

Actually making a quick test, adding my user **running** (let's call him my_user) rabbitmq to */etc/security/limits.conf* the following:

```
my_user           soft    nofile          65000
my_user           hard    nofile          65000
```

Then login out and back again, starting rabbitmq, and checking the number of file descriptors as you did, I obtain:

```
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,64900},...
```

So I can conclude that it works. Now I highly suspect from what you are writing that the user running rabbitmq is not the root user, but a different one. However the increase of max file descriptors seems only applied to the root user, consequently no differences is seen running rabbitmq.

To check it in more detail, it would be good that you post the "service" script ran when you enter:

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```

Now if you want to make sure your modifications worked, you could start directly rabbitmq as *root* (which I don't recommend for production)

Answer (score 0):

Configure `/etc/systemd/system.conf`

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=1048576
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file

The most straightforward way to adjust the per-user limit for RabbitMQ on distributions that do not use systemd is to edit the /etc/default/rabbitmq-server (provided by the RabbitMQ Debian package) or rabbitmq-env.conf to invoke ulimit before the service is started.

so you can modify /etc/default/rabbitmq-server file, this works for me!